# Backbone JS for User Interface over Restful API

Tags: backbone.js

I am writing a UI using Backbone JS. The backend exposes a REST API that backbone JS uses in its MVC approach. So far,  everything works as expected in terms of rendering the REST resource. I.e. I defined model and view for `/as` and `/bs`, I switch between the two using routing.

Now I would like to add a form for adding `/bs` so that I can POST new `b` instances. Part of the form would be a combo box, where the user selects from an option of possible `/as`. I started attaching the form to the templating code for the rendering of the list `/bs`. But for the form, I would require to get `/as`, too. *How is this supposed to work?*

Suppose that I have a template for `/bs` rendering, that iterates over every item `b`. The form should go after the table, and obtain information about  `/as`.

```
                 <% _.each(items, function(item) { %>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <%= item.name %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= item.description %>
                    </td>
                <% }); %>
```

One way to do this would be to extend the response for `GET /bs` to include all `/as`, which doesnt feel restful.

Another option would be to let the BListView fetch these values and supply it as another option to the template.

What is the practice here?

Comment: *"I started attaching the form to the templating code for the rendering of the list /bs. But for the form, I would require to get /as, too. How is this supposed to work?"* this part is not clear. In your explanation `/as` mean a route that has a view and model. What do you mean you want this for the form? Do you want to render a view within another view? Please try to rephrase the question

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple collections inside your view. Granted, if you use `collection: myCollection` when creating the view, then `myCollection` will be the "main" collection but that's it. You can go ahead and add in your `initialize()` method any extra collections you want

```
initialize: function() {
  this.anotherCollection = new Backbone.Collection(...);
  // then listen for any event, let's say 'update'
  this.listenTo(this.anotherCollection, 'update', function() {
    //do something in your view, usually, call this.render()
  });
  this.anotherCollection.fetch();
}
```

This `anotherCollection` however won't get passed in automatically in your template though. You'd have to manually pass it.

```
template: _.template(theTemplate, {otherCollection: this.anotherCollection})
```